# is this a spam email or real

Tags: email, upgrade, security

Message ID : <201812262203.wBQM3RsD009630@web1.gohost.sk>
Sent Date : Wed, 26 Dec 2018 22:03:27 +0000
From : magento@gohost.sk
Sender MailID : magento@gohost.sk
Reply To : magento@gohost.sk
To : events@theiet.org
Subject : Critical vulnerability found in Magento, upgrade necessary

------------------------- Contents -------------------------

gohost.sk web1
Recently a vulnerability in Magento was discovered that allows attackers to gain unauthorized access to your webshop. This unfortunately also means attackers can thereby access all information in your webshop including your customer database and the backoffice.

List of vulnerable systems
The vulnerability is found in all Magento versions. Both users of Magento Community and Magento Enterprise are urged to update their webshop as soon as possible.

How to install the update
The vulnerability is resolved by applying patch SUPEE-5344. In order to activate the update you will have to install the patch and flush the cache.

Click the link bellow to update.

https://update.magento.center/admin/?e=ZXZlbnRzQHRoZWlldC5vcmc=

Â© 2018 Magento, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Comment: Do you have the patch applied? Also, I wouldn't click any links form that email, made sure I had all the patches installed and ignored this email.

Answer (score 3):

This is spam/scam. Do not click the link and ignore the mail.

update.magento.center is not an official Magento domain, also SUPEE-5344 is about 3 years old.